# Unity - Canvas screen size scaling making very small elements disappear on low resolutions

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to set-up my game's HUD so that it scales properly at any resolution, and I ran into a problem I haven't been able to solve yet.

My game uses a dynamic crosshair which consists of 4 images (no sprites, just an Image element with a color) of 2x8/8x2 size, depending on the orientation.

Depending on if you're moving or not, the crosshair gap increases by increasing the X/Y positions of the 4 pieces of the crosshair to show that the accuracy of the weapon is being reduced.

This works and scales perfectly at almost any resolution, but in very low resolutions such as 640x480, the crosshair disappears completely. My guess is that the crosshair images are being shrinked to scale for this resolution, and this causes the width or height of the images to become 0, making the crosshair invisible. If I increase the width or height to 3 pixels, then the crosshair doesn't dissapear at this resolution, but that's not a viable solution. I want the width/height to be 2 pixels.

This is my canvas scaler setup:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dqb1.jpg

And this is the crosshair setup:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAvPa.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOsKC.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuuXR.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWJKI.jpg

This is what happens at different resolutions:

1920x1080 (looks fine): https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxwwk.jpg

1024x768 (looks fine): https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJsfW.jpg

640x480 (crosshair becomes invisible): https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1NXJ.jpg

Any ideas on how to solve this issue? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Use a second canvas with the scaler set to constant pixel size

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code (if any) as **text** rather than as a screenshot. On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].